# How do I use arithmetic powers of AMPscript to finish this function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, math

```
%%[

var @abc=10

var @def=12



set @sum= /*  THIS PART */



]%%
```

Comment: are you referencing the ampscript function reference provided earlier?

Comment: I need to take the following two variables (abc & def) add them together then print the sum as its own variable

Comment: It looks like a test question pasted directly into SFSE. Please take time to do some basic research before asking questions here

Comment: Hi @Lukas, It is not a test question, rather a tutorial I am struggling with. I am trying to learn (I already graduated college but this is out of my field)

Comment: This is the second question that you have posted within an hour that can easily be solved by looking in the SFMC AMPscript documentation. Please take the time to do your own research prior to coming here. This forum is designed to support, learn and teach, not to give free solutions or dev work.

Comment: @Gortonington Thank you for the response. Today was my first time ever working with AMPscript and I had no previous knowledge. I did look at the SFMC AMPscript documentation and came up with my own answer. I posted this as I was trying to see if it was correct and learn, not get free answers.  I apologize it it may have come off the wrong way. 
Originally came up with  "

%%[
var @abc=10
var @def=12

set sum = add(abc def)]%% "

However this did not give me the right output

Comment: Then convey this research and attempts in your questions. Provide as much details around the issue as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the sum of `@abc` and `@def`, you can use the Add function:

```
%%[
var @abc=10
var @def=12

set @sum = add(@abc,@def)
]%%
```

**Reference:** [Add (Official doc)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Add.htm) or [Add (ampscript guide)](https://ampscript.guide/add/)

Comment: Thank you. I came up with something similar but I forgot the last part and messed up my whole equation. Thank you!